# :before element not displaying properly in firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why does firefox misplace the :before element??

```
<div id='remember_forgot' class='no_hl'>
    <div>
        <input id='remember_me' type='checkbox'>
        <label for='remember_me'>Remember me</label>
    </div>
</div>

* {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.3;
    font-weight: normal;
}
input[type='checkbox'] {
    display: none;
}
#remember_forgot {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 2px 0;
}
#remember_forgot>div {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#remember_me+label:before {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    float: left;  
    width: 13px;  
    height: 13px;  
    margin-right: 4px;

    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 0.8;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#remember_me:checked+label:before {
    content:'✓';
    color: black;
}
#remember_me+label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#remember_me+label:hover {
    color: #e1b941;
}
#remember_me,
#remember_me+label,
#forgot {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#remember_me+label {
    transition: 0.2s all;
}
```

All of the relevant code is here in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kjf8h5m6/7/

When I open it in chrome the checkbox :before element is properly centered:
[image]

But when it is viewed in firefox the checkbox looks like it is not centered: 
[image]

This is very annoying.. please help!

Comment: Man if you find that "very annoying" you're never going to make it as a web dev! All in the game.

Comment: set heights & line-heights, I'm usually able to clear up these issues that way. But like the dude above me said. All in the game.

Comment: yes the height and line height is set, as you can see in the code

Comment: And thanks madbreaks, but you can save the pep talk for somebody else

Answer (score 0):

[image]

(Left is chrome, right is firefox)

Removing the wildcard line-height: `*{line-height:1.3;}`, and adding a line-height of 1.5 to the label element solves this in both Firefox and Chrome.

Working fix: http://jsfiddle.net/kjf8h5m6/9/

Comment: hey man thanks for trying but the fix does not appear to be working in firefox but it actually appears to be worse. Do you think that running on linux has anything to do with it?